# UrlGenerationError No route matches on one computer but not on the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm learning Ruby on Rails for the first time, and have been trying to setup my laptop to continue where I was on my desktop with my project. I had some issues yesterday of my laptop running Ruby through rvm and desktop running through rbenv, so I fixed that. Now however, I am getting the following error on my laptop but everything works fine on my laptop.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Categories#index

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-header"><%= link_to 'housing', category_path(@housing) %></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
```

I believe it should work. If I understand the code right, I am linking to my housing category via the category path by passing in the @housing parameter.

Like I said, this works on my desktop.

Code as follows thanks in advance for any help.

output from my rake routes command with the route I am trying to use...

```
category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)    categories#show
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftbar">
    <a href="#"><h1>rubyslist</h1></a>
    <ul>
      <a href="#"><%= link_to 'post a classifieds', new_listing_path %></a>
      <li>my account</li>
    </ul>
      <p>search shiplist</p>
      <%= form_tag search_listings_path, :method => 'get' do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      </p>
      <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="center-column" >
    <div class="center-one">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-header"><%= link_to 'housing', category_path(@housing) %></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <% @housing.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
            <ul class="left-list">
              <li><%= link_to subcategory.name, category_subcategory_path(@housing, subcategory) %></li>
            </ul>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-header"><%= link_to 'roommates', category_path(@roommates) %></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <% @roommates.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
            <ul>
              <li><%= link_to subcategory.name, category_subcategory_path(@roommates, subcategory) %></li>
            </ul>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-header"><%= link_to 'for sale', category_path(@forsale) %></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <% @forsale.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
            <ul class="left-list">
              <li><%= link_to subcategory.name, category_subcategory_path(@forsale, subcategory) %></li>
            </ul>
            <% end %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightbar">
    <!-- Links to the pages via routes match -->
    <ul class="rightbar-top">
      <!-- /help -->
      <li><%= link_to 'help and faq', help_path%></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'avoid scams and fraud', scams_path%></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'personal safety tips', safety_path%></li>
      <li class="rightbar-top"><%= link_to 'terms of use', terms_path%></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'privacy policy', privacy_path%></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'about shiplist', about_path%></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'contact us', contact_path%></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
  #Creates CRUD actions for categories
  resources :categories do
    #Append sub-categories to categories with CRUD
    resources :subcategories
  end

  #Performs the search
  resources :listings do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end

  #Set homepage to index of categories
  root 'categories#index'

  #Matches the pages help action to a get request
  #for the help page with page controller in help
  #function of pages controller
  match '/help', to: 'pages#help', via: :get
  match '/scams', to: 'pages#scams', via: :get
  match '/safety', to: 'pages#safety', via: :get
  match '/about', to: 'pages#about', via: :get
  match '/contact', to: 'pages#contact', via: :get
  match '/privacy', to: 'pages#privacy', via: :get
  match '/terms', to: 'pages#terms', via: :get
  match '/subcategories/find_by_category', to: 'subcategories#find_by_category', via: :post
end
```

categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    #The index page of our categories controller
    def index
        @categories = Category.all
        @housing = @categories[0]
        @roommates = @categories[1]
        @forsale = @categories[2]
    end

    def show
        @listings = Listing.where(category_id: params[:id])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the command

```
rake db:seed
```

Fixed the problem.